# google docs api folder

Tags: java, api, directory

I'm trying to develop one java function to retrieve the id of one specific folder over Google Docs, but the documentation over this language is poor and  have problems to develop it. Until now I've can make this, but don't work, it never show my the document id of my folder

```
public void findfolder(String folderName) throws MalformedURLException,IOException,ServiceException{

URL feedUrla=new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/folder");

DocumentQuery query = new DocumentQuery(feedUrl);
query.setTitleQuery(folderName);
query.setTitleExact(true);
DocumentListFeed feed=null;

try {
feed = client.getFeed(query, DocumentListFeed.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ServiceException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

for (DocumentListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
System.out.println(entry.getDocId());
}
}`
```